# Display first 4 digits of id column from mysql table

Tags: php

I have a session that pulls information from a database

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
```

I am wanting to display a "shorter" version of this id as a "short id" in the webpage. the id is 16 digits long I want to only display the first 4 digits.

I tried

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['id']-12; ?>
```

But it only gave me a weird number like this:

```
5.3830822562889E+15
```

The original id is: `5383082256288945` so I am wanting to display: `5383`

Comment: try "select x as decimal(0,3)

Comment: how can you accept an answer with mistake...? it should help future visitors...  let him edit the post then you can accept that answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
<?php session_start(); echo substr($_SESSION['id'], 0, 4); ?>
```

Comment: changed `0, 3` to `0, 4` and it did what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `substr` function in php. The second parameter is start index, if it is negative start counting it from the end, and the second parameter is the length of the sub string you need.

`echo substr('5383082256288945', 0, 4);` gives you `5383`.

See here for docs: [PHP Substring Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

In your case:

```
<?php session_start();
   $id=substr($_SESSION['id'],0,4);
   echo $id;
 ?>
```

From PHP docs:

```
<?php
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f

// Accessing single characters in a string
// can also be achieved using "square brackets"
$string = 'abcdef';
echo $string[0];                 // a
echo $string[3];                 // d
echo $string[strlen($string)-1]; // f

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$id=5383082256288945;
$rest = substr($id, 0, 4);
echo $rest;
```

Check [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) for more information.